# Gradient Descent with Tanh, 0 gradient on incorrect classification?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, loss-function

The derivative of the `tanh(x)` activation function is `1-tanh^2(x)`.
When performing gradient descent on this function, this derivative becomes part of the gradients for the weights.

For example, with `Mean Squared Error`: `dL/dw = (tanh(x) - y)*(1 - tanh^2(x))*dx/dw`

When `tanh(x)` is equal to `1` or `-1`, the term `tanh^2(x)` becomes `1`.

This means that if the right class is predicted, then `1-tanh^2(x)` equals `0`, and so the gradient of the loss becomes `0`, and so the weights do not update.

However, for the same reason, this would appear to mean that if the exact wrong class is predicted, then the gradient is still `0`, thus causing no update. Presumably, this is the opposite of what you want to happen.

Is this a problem? If so, how is this problem avoided/amended?

Comment: The `tanh` function is mainly used classification between two classes. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/activation-functions-neural-networks-1cbd9f8d91d6) & [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12754/matching-loss-function-for-tanh-units-in-a-neural-net) might help you

Comment: Please notice that including phrases like "*Edit: slight math error*" in your posts when updating them is meaningless and should be avoided as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is avoided by choosing the prediction values of `0` and `1` for each of the classes (in the case of classification of two classes). I.e. you would not normally one-hot-encode to negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Good news is that `tanh(x)` only becomes +/- 1 when `x` is +/- infinity, so you do not need to worry too much about this.

However, the gradients do become dampened for `x` of higher absolute value, so you should:

1. z-normalize your inputs and initialize weights in network the right way [1]
2. Use `ReLU` or its variants (`LeakyReLU`, `PReLU`, etc.) for deeper networks.

For further reading, search "vanishing gradients".

[1] http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf